# MsAccess Strange Linked Table Issue

Tags: ms-access, odbc, mariadb

Backend: MariaDB
Frontend: MsAccess
On my development platform everything runs fine, but on the client there are some issues I can't explain.

When I open a table say "addresses" or "emails" it has the same amount of records as it supposed to have, except that what it visually displays is the same record over and over again. Sometimes I can see a few other records repeat themselves as well but there is no pattern. It is literally as if all the records are the same.

A curious observation though, if I right click on the linked table and export it to excel, the data exported is shown correctly.

I'm not sure where to look, everything seems similar:

The ODBC Connector: MariaDB ODBC 2.0 Driver (32-bit)
MS Office Pro Plus 2013 32-bit

The Operating systems are 32-bit (non working one) and 64-bit on the fully working one but that shouldn't be an issue.

I do use four databases and it seems like that the issue comes only from tables from one of the four databases.

Is there a setting in Access that might hinder the render of the table?

Comment: This happened once to me on a SQL Server table. Don't quite remember the fix. Try deleting the linked table and re-creating it. Could be corrupted tabledef not cached correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure this happens when you don't have a numeric primary key.

You need to add a column to the table with auto number so that when the Client(linked) MS Access tries to talk to the host(source) MS Access it knows which record you are specifically talking about.

I could be wrong. But check it out.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm a bit perplexed. I found out that of the four computers that use this client, only one of them has the issue. The table in question has an id which is index and unique, and two fields combined are the primary key. I'll have to research more into it.

Comment: I'm disappointed that this is the solution because I don't understand why only one of the four computers are displaying this issue. However after changing the two fields to UNIQUE and then the main table Id to primary, and relinking the table there after... The table displays properly. Hopefully doing this to the tables that require it will fix the other bugs that I have been observing. Thanks ClintB that works. Don't know why, but it does.

Comment: Not sure why it worked on other machines, however the issue is somewhat simple to explain. 
Basically when MS Access wants to update the parent table it needs a unique field to pass through in order to say update record with ID of x.
Instead of update records where name = "x" which could result in multiple records being updated and data issue to follow.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem.  When my coworker opened the linked table, data was strange, but when I opened it, the data was fine.  On my computer, the table was linked WITHOUT a key, but on my coworker's computer, the table was linked WITH a key.  But the selected key was not actually unique.  When we deleted the link, and linked again without the key, the data looks fine.

The previous suggestion works because adding the Auto Number Numeric Primary Key is creating a UNIQUE key.  A Numeric key is not what is fixing the problem, having a Unique key is fixing the problem.  In my case, removing the key (which was NOT Unique) fixed the problem, because it removed the inconsistency:  the linked table was told the column was a key, but that column was not actually unique in the underlying data, so Access was "confused".